# Is generic resolution possible in Fortran with unlimited polymorphic entities

Tags: fortran

When you try to *overload* subroutines by means of generic interfaces, or combining modules or through type-bound procedures, one has to take into account that any of the procedures with the same generic name must have *distinguishable or incompatible arguments*.

When using unlimited polymorphic entities, you can quickly run in such problems as demonstrated in this incredible educational example:

```
INTERFACE foobar
  SUBROUTINE foo(x)
    INTEGER :: x
  END SUBROUTINE foo
  SUBROUTINE bar(x)
    CLASS(*) :: x
  END SUBROUTINE bar
END INTERFACE foobar
```

Here, `foo(x)` conflicts with `bar(x)` as the argument of `bar` can also be an `INTEGER`.

This particular problem can be resolved using the `SELECT TYPE` construct in a new subroutine which replaces the generic interface:

```
SUBROUTINE foobar(x)
  CLASS(*) :: x
  SELECT TYPE (x)
    TYPE IS INTEGER
      CALL foo(x)
    CLASS default
      CALL bar(x)
  END SELECT
END SUBROUTINE foobar
```

However, sometimes such constructs can become tedious and unwanted.

Are there other ways to implement such *specialisation* without the usage of the `SELECT TYPE` construct?

Comment: Specialization is not a term the Fortran standard uses. I changed that to *generic disambiguation*, maybe *generic resolution* would be better.  Anyway, the word specialization evokes C++ templates, at least to me.

Comment: one nasty way would be to create a preprocessor macro which would generate `SUBROUTINE foobar` for you from supplied arguments, accepted types and corresponding "handlers"... :)

Comment: @VladimirF Agreed that the term _specialisation_ is questionable and would suggest it to replace it with _generic resolution_. "Disambiguation" is not something I would search for (but that is just a personal opinion)

Comment: @ewcz preprocessor syntax might be possible, but I would like to stick to standard Fortran.

Comment: Generic resolution occurs at compile time.  SELECT TYPE is a runtime action.  Which one are you chasing?

Comment: @IanH would be nice to have something like `CLASS(*, EXCEPT=INTEGER)` in order to make the `INTERFACE` block valid...

Comment: @ewcz and what happens when the dynamic type (a runtime concept) of an unlimited polymorphic actual argument is integer?  Unlimited polymorphic objects are not props for generic programming.

Comment: @IanH, the idea would be to avoid `SELECT TYPE` usage as such constructs can become very tedious (imagine a procedure with two `CLASS(*)` dummy variables, this already requires nested `SELECT TYPE` constructs)

Comment: @IanH, could you elaborate on your comment "Unlimited polymorphic objects are not props for generic programming". I understand they are for sure not as powerful and efficient as templates in C++, but it is possible and currently the best we've got. Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I think above usage of the SELECT TYPE construct is best way to implement such requirement.
As per Fortran 2018 specification usage of INTERFACE foobar in above program is NOT specification confirming as integer x and class(*) x are TKR compatible. Compiler should generate compile time error for above program.
I think there is no better workaround other than replacing generic interface by a procedure and use select type construct to call specific procedures.

## Snippet from Fortran 2018 specification:

Restrictions on generic declarations:

Two dummy arguments are distinguishable if:
they are both data objects or known to be functions, and neither is TKR compatible with the other.